# I have a problem with variable fonts: The function 'FontVariation' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, variable-fonts

[flutter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXVWy.png)

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snnHi.png)

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnTPS.png)

[font file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USxAS.png)

In flutter, I have a problem when using variable fonts: The function 'FontVariation' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'FontVariation', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'FontVariation'. Could it be that I didn't import something?

```dart
style: TextStyle(
    fontVariations: const <FontVariation>[
        FontVariation("wght", 500),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've imported the dart ui package.

```
import 'dart:ui';
```